# Incrementing iterator and passing the argument in a recursion loop

Tags: c++, recursion

I want to print out the values of a vector using a recursive function.

```
void pvec(int cnt, std::vector<int> vec) {
    if(cnt < vec.size()) {
        std::cout << vec[cnt++] << std::endl;
        return pvec(cnt,vec);
    }
}
```

Instead of using vector subscript I wanted to use iterators. However, when I write up a similar function where I pass an iterator for the first argument and try to return the function with an incremented iterator the loop doesn't stop and I get a segmentation fault. Why is this?

```
void pvec(std::vector<int>::iterator po, std::vector<int> vec)
{
    if(po < vec.end()) {
        std::cout << *po++ << std::endl;
        return pvec(po,vec);
    }
}
```

I did try making po a reference and this didn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- *vec.end() is incorrect.
- What is the purpose of the return value ?
- You should use reference to avoid to copy vector each time.
- Add some constness.

Fixed version:

```
void pvec(std::vector<int>::const_iterator po, const std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    if(po != vec.end()) {
        std::cout << *po++ << std::endl;
        pvec(po, vec);
    }
}
```

The crash come from *vec.end()
The "strange loop behaviour" come from the comparison of iterators from different vectors (as the vector is copied each time).

Comment: Yes sorry. Initially I was thinking of another way and began with a int function. But you are right the return serves no purpose.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, though.

Comment: @H2CO3: answer edited to explain the crash and the "strange loop behavior".

Comment: It does. @LarryPel below provided a more thorough explanation but basically the iterator po just keeps iterating through the first copy but the comparison is with the subsequent copies. There is no relation between the two and so it loops forever.

Comment: If the vector needs to be referenced to point to the original object, why can we omit referencing the original iterator? Why does the iterator not get copied every time in the same way? From what is being explained it seems like the iterator iterators through the first copy continuously.

Answer (score 3):

> I get a segmentation fault. Why is this?

Because your code invokes undefined behavior.

```
return *(vec.end());
```

is illegal, since `vec.end()` "points" **one past** the last element. It does **not** point to the last element. Perhaps you meant

```
return vec.end()[-1];
```

instead? If so, you need to check if the vector is empty before accessing the last element.

Comment: I seem to get a segmentation fault whether I return *(vec.end()), *(vec.end()-1) or any other integer. I am not actually using this integer anyway in my output. I just left it in because it seemed to work for the above program.

Comment: @Comrade Then you need to drastically re-design and re-think your code. "I just left in stuff because it worked somewhere else" is like saying "I'll shout 'I hate communists!' in Russia because it worked in Germany"...

Comment: The vector is created on the stack (since is passed by copy), so I don't think the segfault is because an access to *vec.end(). Probably is caused by a stack overflow of infinite calls to the recursive function.

Comment: @LarryPel There's a termination condition in the function. That hardly causes infinite recursion. And anyway, it's completely pointless to reason about the program's behavior, since it's undefined.

Comment: The return *vec.end() just returns whatever comes after the vector.

Comment: @Comrade No, it doesn't. It invokes undefined behavior, so it's free to do whatever it wants.

Comment: *vec.end() is wrong, of course. You never should use that code in any circumstances, What I'm saying is that, since the vec is on the stack, *vec.end() will just return the content near the vector on the stack, and dereferencing that memory address won't cause a segfault.

Comment: @LarryPel I'm sorry, but 1. the C++ standard is not concerned with any kind of "stack" or whatnot. 2. Do you know every single C++ standard library implementation in the world? Do you know how all of them implements `std::vector`? I suspect you don't. 3. If we are trying to reason the unreasonable: elements in `std::vector` are typically dynamically allocated (on the "heap", if there's a heap in an architecture). So `operator[]` doesn't access stack but heap memory.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the "vec" argument is passed by copy, so each call of the recursive function will result in a new vector object and comparing iterators of different vectors is simply wrong. That's why your comparison "po < vec.end()" and the recursion never ends.

Also, I don't understand the purpose of returning a value. You should fix the second argument to pass by constant reference and don't return anything:

```
void pvec(std::vector<int>::iterator po, const std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    if(po < vec.end()) {
        std::cout << *po++ << std::endl;
        pvec(po,vec);
    }    
}
```

Comment: and don't return.. anything, probably? or and to return void